# Drop Event Not Preventing Default

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, jquery-events

I've the following: http://jsfiddle.net/KywJT/

```
function dragEnter(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(evt.target).addClass('over');
}

function dragLeave(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(evt.target).removeClass('over');
}

function drop(evt) {
   evt.stopPropagation();
   evt.preventDefault();
   $(evt.target).removeClass('over');
}

jQuery( function ( $ ) {

  var $box = $( "#box" );
  $box.bind("dragenter", dragEnter);
  $box.bind("dragleave", dragLeave);
  $box.bind("drop", drop);
});
```

I'm using Chrome version 24.0.1312.52 m and last jQuery (1.8.3).
When I drop a file into the box, browser is not preventing default beaviour.
Can you please help me?

P.S. dragexit is deprecated correct?

Comment: It works for me and I didn't modify a single line of code

Comment: Oo.. It was just working until I updated Chrome :| `Version 24.0.1312.52 m`  now it just opens the file in the browser

Comment: K, I'm not crazy. Any fix?

Comment: @user1824269 I'm not sure.. still playing around with it.  It was just working, was going to paste my Chrome browser version.. But it said I need to restart browser to update.. Once I restarted it didn't work anymore..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should fix the issue for you.

```
jQuery( function ( $ ) {
    var $box = $( "#box" );
    $box.bind("dragenter", dragEnter);
    $box.bind("dragleave", dragLeave);
    $box.bind("drop", drop);

    $(document).bind('dragover', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem to work on jsfiddle. BTW, to stop bubbling, you need to use e.stopPropagation(), not e.preventDefault()

Comment: Worked for me outside jsfiddle, I think it's because of dragover event. Should I add stop propagation method?

Comment: yes. You don't have to prevent drop. Updated my answer. I was just typing. I didn't try. :(

Answer (score 17):

If you want the drop event to be fired in Google Chrome, a dragover listener has to be defined before, even if the function doesn't do anything at all. I don't know why, it's weird... but clearly identified and easy to reproduce :)
Lost 2 hours on that sh*t yesterday :/ hope this helps

Comment: I wish I could upvote this multiple times. Thank you thank you thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I used answers to this question and wrote the code I want:

HTML:

```
<div id="image_holder" ondragover="dragEnter(this,event)"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
function dragEnter(a,evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(evt.target).addClass('over');

    $(a).bind("dragleave", dragLeave);
    $(a).bind("drop", drop);

    $(document).bind('dragover', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    return false;
}

function dragLeave(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(evt.target).removeClass('over');
    return false;
}

function drop(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(evt.target).removeClass('over');
}
```

This has the privilege you can use it easily for different elements in page.